# I am facing an error while using spinner

Tags: android

I am creating a death calculator app , which calculates the D-day (well, it's a hypothetical app but as I am beginner I found it good and fun ). In my layout I want user to enter his name , age then I have put two check boxes with question "Do you smoke" yes or no . then I have put a spinner which is consist of disease . User have to select the one from which he is suffering . Now you got an idea of what I am creating .

```
 button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {





                    String name = editText.getText().toString();


                    if (yes.isChecked()) {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;
                        int b ;
                        int l;
                        l = 80 ;
                        int y ;
                        y = l - age ;

                        c = y - 7;
                        final int z;
                        b = 2016 + c;

                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year" + b) + "");

                    } else {
                        if (no.isChecked()) {
                            int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                            int c;

                            int l;
                            l = 80;
                            int y;
                            y = l - age;
                            c = y + 10;

                            b = 2016 + c;
                            editText3.setText((name + "you might die in the year" + b) + "");
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
```

This is the code of button . As you can see that the int b is the ultimate result. now I want to use this int in spinner . For example if this his age comes b = 32 . now I want to use this value of b (32 ) in spinner . Now this is where I am stuck .

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("none,i am healthy");
        list.add("Diabetes");
        list.add("cancer");
        list.add("HIV/AIDS");
        list.add("Tuberculosis");
        list.add("Coronary Artery");
        list.add("respiratory disease");
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
//        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,  int position, long id) {

                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
              List list = new  ArrayList ();

                list.add("Diabetes");
                list.add("cancer");
                list.add("HIV/AIDS");
                list.add("Tuberculosis");
                list.add("respiratory disease");
                list.add("Coronary Artery");
                ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();



                if (list.get(position).equals("Diabetes")) {

                  //if user selects diabetes then his age (b) would get minus by 5.how do i do this ?// 



                   };
```

Comment: i dont know how to get that value in spinner which came as an output from button @PriyankGupta

Comment: Why you want to use the end result to the spinner.. ???

Comment: Create an array of the items you want in your spinner. Then use `ArrayAdapter` to create an adapter. Then use `setAdapter()` to populate your spinner.

Comment: that is what i have done @PriyankGupta

Comment: So, what values do you get in your spinner?

Comment: i am only getting the values of the checkbox selection , 
i.e. if user enter his age he have to select the checkbox of "do you smoke ?" then he comes on the spinner . i am getting the values of checkbox only even if user selects anything from spinner the value does not change . it remains same  .
@PriyankGupta

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your code:

`dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

after you've made changes to the list of the adapter.

Comment: let me send you an image of my code so that u would understand it better . 

facebook would be good :)